# Why is my url in the following google appengine (python) yaml config file not recognized?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

I have the following config file for my google appengine app in python:

```
application: testapp-94974206
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /helloworld
  script: helloworld.application

- url: /
  script: helloworld.application
```

when calling the url with no prefix (/) I get my "helloworld" app called, while when calling with /helloworld I get a 404 not found error page. What is wrong with the declaration of "/helloworld" above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [YAML file url and script in GAE python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311000/yaml-file-url-and-script-in-gae-python)

Answer (score 1):

My question is actually close to another one that has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311000/yaml-file-url-and-script-in-gae-python).

It turns out that the /helloworld url is actually well routed by the appengine, but then the culprit is the WSGI router that parses the whole absolute URL and not just the one relative to /helloworld, as I thought it would.