# Setting multiple handlers with Python App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I just cannot seem to get multiple handlers working. I'm using Google App Engine with Python. The base URL returns "Hello world!", as expected, but I keep getting a 404 error when I try to visit "/girl".

As far as I can tell I'm doing exactly what is specified in the docs:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig

And in this similar question:

[YAML file url and script in GAE python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311000/yaml-file-url-and-script-in-gae-python)

and yet trying all variants I can think of on these models does not resolve my 404 problem. I am a beginner and don't really understand how the app.yaml file works, thus I'm pretty sure that I'm not specifying the handlers correctly. But I don't know how to fix it.

app.yaml

```
application: multiapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: ./girl/.*
  script: girl.app

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

main.py

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello world!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

girl.py

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            self.response.write('Hey girl!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/',MainHandler),
    ('/girl/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

**Added:** Different organization of the project could definitely avoid having to solve this problem, but I would also like to know why setting these multiple handlers isn't working to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old thread, and that you sort of got your answer, but I want to give a better explanation of what was happening, as I have just found the answer to your fundamental question: ***How to split handlers into different files?***

The key problem is that you are working with regular expressions, both when you declare your *WSGIApplication*

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/girl/', GirlHandler)
], debug=True)
```

and in your *yaml* file

```
handlers:

- url: ./girl/.*
  script: girl.app

- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

The path in your yaml `url: regex` must be the full path from your webapp domain. So if your domain is [localhost:8080](http://localhost:8080/) then in your yaml file yo should add the url from *localhost:8080* onwards. If you type `url: /girl/.*`
you're asking the browser to match *domain+regex*: [localhost:8080/girl/.*](http://localhost:8080/girl/.*)

This means:

1. match this part exactly: localhost:8080/girl/
2. match any characters that follow the first part (as that's what ".*"
   means in a regex)

So the following yaml statement:

```
handlers:

- url: /girl/.*
  script: girl.app
```

means that for any url of the form ***domain/girl/*** *anything (or nothing)* use the the **app variable** in **girl.py** file `app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(...)`

The first implication of this, is there is no purpose in writing a handler for a url that girl.py will never handle, such as when you coded:

girl.py

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            self.response.write('Hey girl!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/',MainHandler),
], debug=True)
```

You will never use this main handler, as it will only 'activate' when you browse for *domain/*, but you said in your yaml file that you only wanted girl.py to handler urls of the form *domain/girl/something*. It's a contradiction

This means that for your setup to work, in girl.py you should only write handlers for urls that match the regex in your yaml. in this case, any regex that is also accepted by `/girl/.*`.

As a sidenote, if you wanted your girlHandler to work on either *domain/girl* and *domain/girl/* you should use this regex in your yaml file:

```
handlers:

- url: ./girl(?:/.*)?
  script: girl.app

- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

as this makes the `/.*` part optional

Hope this helps anyone reaching this question, as an insight of how webapp2 calls each handler depending on the url given

Answer (score 1):

You should bundle all your routes together in one file, and have different handlers for different routes.

main.py

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello world!')

class GirlHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hey Girl!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/girl/', GirlHandler)
], debug=True)
```

then in your app.yaml you only have to link to `main.app`

```
application: multiapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

You don't need multiple `webapp2.WSGIApplication` instances.

Comment: Thanks for this. What I'm ultimately trying to do is combine several different apps under one domain, so that I will have something like xxx.appspot.com/app1,
xxx.appspot.com/app2,
etc.
I think it would be easier to organize if I kept them in separate files. Is it not possible to do handlers in the way I have outlined above?

Comment: It's possible but why would you want that?

Comment: If it's possible then why aren't my handlers working? :)  The reason I'd like to do it this way is because it seems weird to me to be sending people to a different domain whenever they visit a different part of my page. Also doesn't it make cookies/user sign-in harder to manage?

Comment: *it seems weird to me to be sending people to a different domain whenever they visit a different part of my page.* can't you just handle different pages with different handles? You don't need a different app for each page you have on your site

Comment: When it is only one page, that is fine, but I am talking about adapting an entire app to go under each xxx.appspot.com/appx route, not just a single page, and each app will have its own set of multiple handlers. I could definitely do this by just naming each handler with an app-specific prefix, but I think it makes my main.py file look messy. Maybe I should give it some more thought...

Comment: A different app should have a different domain, why do you think it would be weird to link to a different domain if it's a different app?

Comment: The apps are related. I am thinking about each app being a different game, but I want there to be one common sign-in/main page from which you can go to the different games. Now that I'm writing this it is occurring to me that what I am thinking of clearly calls for one master webapp2.WSGIApplication, not multiple ones, and thus I just need to find a way to keep my handler names organized.

Comment: Yeah that sound reasonable :-)

Answer (score 1):

You *could* have central routing while keeping handlers in separate files with something along these lines in `main.py`:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/girl/.*', "girl.MainHandler")
    ('/.*', MainHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Another possibility of running largely independent "apps" while still be able to share *some* info across them (like authentication) would be to make them [modules of the main app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/). While offering more flexibility in the long run they do have a non-neglijible learning curve (and docs aren't always up2date for them)

Answer (score 0):

Organizational issues aside, the reason this wasn't working was that I didn't include a trailing slash.

"/girl" (no slash) returns 404;
"/girl/" (with slash) renders the page.

Also the lines in app.yaml should be:

```
handlers:
- url: /girl/.*
  script: girl.app
```